# How to implement group breaks, running totals, group total

Tags: delphi

Often I have to process an input dataset from the beginning until end of file is reached while performing calculations like running totals, group total an, at the end, the grand total.

Many report builders tools offer this functionality out of the box: group breaks and ResetGroup property.

Can someone suggest me how to implement this in delphi pseudo-code with the use of TDatasets ?.

Comment: A TDataset is an abstraction for data, while groups and running totals are something that's used for reporting. Reports are often done using data that comes from a TDataset, but that doesn't mean TDataset has (or should) have anything to do with the actual computing of totals, sub-totals, running-totals or groups. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can do both in SQL using Analytics and using aggregates in TClientDataset. So what's wrong with this question? Those data could be also displayed outside a report. QuantumGrid for example allows them.

Comment: devex Quantum Grid + Express Printing System would provide a complete UI plus a printing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple idea:

Write some code that creates these sum/average/min/max type features. Not very hard.

```
   procedure TMyDataModule1.Totals;
   var
      group:TSalesGroup;  { in-memory data holder object used only for sales totals by group }
   begin
      ClearOldValues; {Set TotalSales := 0, etc}
      dataset.First;
      while not dataset.Eof do begin
         group := DetermineGroupOfThisRecord; { TSalesGroup, has property TotalSales }
         group.DoGroupTotals; { TotalSales := TotalSales + dbSalesfield.AsCurrency; }
         doGlobalTotalsForOneRow; { TotalSales := TotalSales + dbSalesfield.AsCurrency;  }
         dataset.Next;
      end;
      DumpMyResults; {you write this}
    end;
```

For running totals, look at the Calculated Field Types, they are available in all of the dataset versions, not just in client dataset.   I like Arjen's answer (use ClientDataSet) but you might want to do somethings without creating a copy of your data into a client dataset. So try and find what you can do with regular datasets too.

Comment: Tank you Warren this is exactly what I was looking for, for the very same reasons you pointed out against TClientDataSets.

Only one question: what about the difference in the following two lines?

    group.DoGroupTotals; { TotalSales := TotalSales +  dbSalesfield.AsCurrency; }
    doGlobalTotalsForOneRow; { TotalSales := TotalSales + dbSalesfield.AsCurrency;  }

Comment: one was to be the totals for just that group (Sales per group) and one was to show that you might have a total for all groups.  You could probably just do the group totals, and then sum all the group sums, or you could calculate two complete sets of totals,  averages, etc, your call.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ClientDataset [Aggregates fields](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Specifying_Aggregates)

Grouping and aggregates: [example](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/Grouping+and+Aggregates/)

Answer (score 0):

If your database suports it, you can calculate also them within SQL. Look for SQL analytics functions. For large datasets sometimes it is better to have them calculated server side, especially when you don't need to move the whole resultset client side.